# GitHub Pages errors with travis-ci and Gemfile

Tags: ruby, github, jekyll

I have a jekyll site: https://github.com/elfet/elfet.github.io with Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'github-pages'
```

Locally everything is working great. But i got some errors on GitHub Pages.

Travis CI have build status: Errored https://travis-ci.org/elfet/elfet.github.io

So i do not know what to do. Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The travis job mentions:

```
/home/travis/build.sh: line 188: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
/home/travis/build.sh: line 191: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

It could be related to your [`.travis.yml`](https://github.com/elfet/elfet.github.io/blob/master/.travis.yml) file, which seems to miss a double quote:

```
language: ruby
script:
  - bundle exec jekyll build"
                           ^^^
                           (where is the opening double-quote?)
```

---

The [OP Medvedev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2546662/medvedev) [reports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20058851/github-pages-errors-with-travis-ci-and-gemfile/20065401#comment29890242_20065401) seeing after that:

```
Liquid Exception: highlight tag was never closed in _posts/2013-02-05-dot-notation-for-array.html/#excerpt
```

Contributor extraordinaire [SLaks](https://stackoverflow.com/users/34397/slaks) documents in "[Jekyll bug: Tag was never closed](http://blog.slaks.net/2013-08-09/jekyll-tag-was-never-closed/)":

> To fix this, you can either fix every post so that the excerpt is valid Liquid markup, or prevent Jekyll from generating the excerpts in the first place.
>   Jekyll does not yet have a way to disable excerpts entirely, so the next-best option is to configure it so that the excerpts are always valid Liquid.
>
> You can do this by setting excerpt_separator to a nonsense string that never appears in your posts, so that the excerpt will include the entire post (which is already known to be valid markup).
>   Better yet, you can set excerpt_separator to an empty string, so that the excerpt will end immediately. This will reduce the amount of work that Jekyll needs to do, making your site build slightly faster.
>
> In short, this bug can be fixed by adding the following line to `_config.yml`:

```
excerpt_separator: ""   # Workaround for http://blog.slaks.net/2013-08-09/jekyll-tag-was-never-closed
```

> Once [#1386](https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll/pull/1386) is released, this line will disable excerpts entirely, adding another miniscule performance boost.

Comment: Thanks! I fixed it. But now i got Generating...   Liquid Exception: highlight tag was never closed in _posts/2013-02-05-dot-notation-for-array.html/#excerpt

Comment: @Medvedev It works locally maybe because you are using a different Jekyll version. See https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll/issues/1401 and http://blog.slaks.net/2013-08-09/jekyll-tag-was-never-closed/

Comment: @Medvedev Great. I have documented your second error message in the answer for more visibility.